# GCP - How to make use of Free Credits and Production Usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can I make use of Free Credits and once its over continue with production billing without disrupting anything?

I'm planning to run 2 `n1-standard-2` instances on GKE and without disruption I want to continue with normal billing. Is this possible? What are the steps for continuing once the free credits are over?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question:

> Can I make use of Free Credits and once its over continue with production billing without disrupting anything?

You must [upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to use Google Cloud after the Free Trial ends

**If you upgrade before the trial is over**, your remaining credit is added to your paid Cloud Billing account and **you can continue** to use the resources you created during the Free Trial **without interruption.**

These are the steps you should follow to upgrade your  Cloud Billing account:

1. Sign in to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.167208574.1900457179.1609772478-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.257541625.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE).
2. Look for the **Free trial status** banner at the top of the page and click on **Activate**

If the Activate button is not visible, on the menu bar, click Free trial status Free trial status icon and the Activate button appears.

And then,  [confirm the upgrade status](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#confirm-status-of-account) of your Cloud Billing account.

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end) when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first. You can upgrade to a paid [Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).